# Spring Integration TCP: How to get local IP address

Tags: spring-integration

I'm new to Spring Integration and experimenting with its TCP support. I have implemented a very basic TCP server that accepts connections and just logs the messages from the clients. This works fine, but I'm stuck in finding out how to get the **local** IP address to which the client has connected (the server machine has multiple IP addresses). It seems that the `MessageHeader`s contain only the **remote** address.

Here's my configuration:

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(2000);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setOutputChannel(requestChannel());
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory());

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PrintService printService() {
        return new PrintService();
    }
}
```

And my `PrintService`:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class PrintService {   
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
    public String print(Message<byte[]> message) {
        // How can I get the local IP address here?
    }
}
```

## Edit 1

Basically, I would like to have the result from `java.net.Socket.getLocalAddress()` available in my `print(...)` function. Maybe like this: `message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS)`

I also tried to add a custom message header by subclassing `TcpMessageMapper` and overriding `supplyCustomHeaders(...)`, but I couldn't  find out how to access the underlying socket.

Comment: Would you mind to share what you want to see and from where it can be picked up? We may consider that as a Framework improvement.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Please see Edit 1 above.

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I would like to have the result from java.net.Socket.getLocalAddress() available in my print(...) function. Maybe like this: message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS)

Yeah, I'd better expose something like `T getTarget()` on the `TcpConnection` to allow to get access to underlying `socket` from the `TcpMessageMapper.supplyCustomHeaders()` implementation...

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter and we'll try to figure out what to do from the Framework perspective.

Meanwhile, as a workaround: I guess you should extend the `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` a bit and override its `initializeConnection(TcpConnectionSupport connection, Socket socket)` to store the `connectionId` <-> `socket` relationship in some global map. Maybe even in your custom `TcpMessageMapper`? Having `connectionId` in the `supplyCustomHeaders()`  you will be able to restore the particular `socket` for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I created [INT-3952](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3952). Regarding your workaround: What would be the appropriate place to remove the `connectionId` <-> `socket` relationship from the global map when the connection is closed?

Comment: How about to do that exactly from your custom `supplyCustomHeaders()`? You even can place that `socket` to the headers. I agree it is dangerous from the Framework perspective, but I guess that should be OK for your application.

Comment: I tried this, but there seem to be cases where `supplyCustomHeaders()` isn't called, e.g. when the client sends an incomplete message. Then the entry for this connection is never removed from the global map.

Comment: Well, than you should clean it up one more time on the failure for that `connection` catching `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks!